# Are Java 8 streams slower than hand written loops?

Tags: java, performance, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to benchmark two different implementations of a `Java` function that checks whether a number contains at least one even digit. The first implementation uses hand written loop, while the second uses a `stream`.

```
public class StreamTest {

public boolean containsEvenDigit(int n) {
    char [] digits = String.valueOf(n).toCharArray();
    for(char d : digits) {
        if(d % 2 == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean containsEvenDigitStreams(int n) {
    return String.valueOf(n).chars().anyMatch(i -> i % 2 == 0);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("============WITHOUT STREAM============");
    long start1 = System.nanoTime();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
        (new StreamTest()).containsEvenDigit(11215 + i);
    }
    long duration1 = (long)(System.nanoTime() - start1)/1_000_000;
    System.out.println("Duration : " + duration1 + " milliseconds.");
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("============USING STREAM============");
    long start2 = System.nanoTime();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
        (new StreamTest()).containsEvenDigitStreams(11215 + i);
    }
    long duration2 = (long)(System.nanoTime() - start2)/1_000_000;
    System.out.println("Duration : " + duration2 + " milliseconds.");
    System.out.println();

}
```

}

In the `main` function, I am not outputting the return values of the functions being tested to eliminate I/O overhead. The outcome shows that the implementation using streams performs much slower than the ones using loop.

```
============WITHOUT STREAM============
Duration : 119 milliseconds.

============USING STREAM============
Duration : 771 milliseconds.
```

Does this mean that `Java` 8 streams are slower than hand written loops?

**Update**: I am now using JMH to benchmark the two functions.

```
public class MyBenchmark {

private boolean containsEvenDigit(int n) {
    char [] digits = String.valueOf(n).toCharArray();
    for(char d : digits) {
        if(d % 2 == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean containsEvenDigitStream(int n) {
    return String.valueOf(n).chars().anyMatch(i -> i % 2 == 0);
}

@State(Scope.Thread)
public static class MyState{
    public int x = 1_357_997_531;
}

@Benchmark
public void testLoop(MyState state, Blackhole blackhole) {
    boolean retVal = containsEvenDigit(state.x);
    blackhole.consume(retVal);
}

@Benchmark
public void testStream(MyState state, Blackhole blackhole) {
    boolean retVal = containsEvenDigitStream(state.x);
    blackhole.consume(retVal);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
    Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
            .include(MyBenchmark.class.getSimpleName())
            .forks(1)
            .build();

    new Runner(opt).run();
}
```

}

This time too the hand written loop beats the stream by an order of about 8.
Here is the result summary.

```
Benchmark                Mode  Cnt        Score        Error  Units
MyBenchmark.testLoop    thrpt  200  3578620.170 ± 207106.919  ops/s
MyBenchmark.testStream  thrpt  200   433884.589 ±  23993.270  ops/s
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103

Comment: in one method you do `toCharArray()` and in the other `chars()` how do you know if the difference is not there? you need to provide the exact same arg to the two methods to test

Comment: This questions isn't the same as https://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/802339
I asked whether Java 8 streams are slower, not about writing a flawless benchmark.

Comment: See: https://jaxenter.com/java-performance-tutorial-how-fast-are-the-java-8-streams-118830.html

Comment: @sank If you write *"I am trying to benchmark two different implementations"*, it is quite expected that someone points you to how to write this benchmark correctly. If you write it correctly, you have your answer.

Comment: *"I asked whether Java 8 streams are slower"* - No you didn't.  You **actually** asked *"Does this [in other words, your benchmark] mean that Java 8 streams are slower than hand written loops?"*.  And the answer to that Question is that your benchmark doesn't mean anything ... because it is flawed.

Comment: I have another dup that asks *when* a stream will be slower than a loop.  And the short answer is ... it is complicated, and Java version specific.

Comment: @StephenC Now I am benchmarking using JMH. The results are the same.

Comment: OK.  Now how have a single "data point".  This says that for this particular example (coded as you have done it) the loop implementation is faster than the stream implementation.  But you can't generalize from a single data point / single example to the conclusion you are attempting to draw.  So, once again, No it doesn't mean that.